# I am trying to get all categories by calling my custom Wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress, categories, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to get all categories by calling Wordpress rest api on in android app.
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
I can get all categories by calling the above url but I have installed category image plugin so I need to get every category image in addition to default schemas.
So I have to make my own custom rest api endpoint.
The following is my code.

But Wordpress function get_categories returns null.
Anyone let me know what is my wrong point in my code?
Why I can't get what I want to get?
I tried to call get_posts function in my custom endpoint function but it also returned null.
So the main goal of this posting why not working calling Wordpress function get_categories and get_posts in my custom endpoint function?

```
register_rest_route($this->namespace, '/'.$this->rest_base, array('methods' => 'GET', 'callback' => array($this, 'get_main_categories')));
...
public function get_main_categories($request) {
$data = get_categories();
$data = rest_ensure_response($data);
return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.
I got the reason.
The functions get_categories returns only category list that has one more posting in it.

Answer (score 0):

if your categoies less than or = 100 use :

http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100

could you give me plugin name (what's category image plugin full name or link) ?